# Stop MongoShell from print variable assignment

Tags: mongodb

I'm running studio 3T and am attempting basic scripting in the intellishell.
If I do a simple variable assignment like

```
var myString= "";
myString = "xyz";
mystring = "abc";
```

it prints "xyz" and "abc" to the console, any way I can prevent this? 
For further context, there are a few purpose print() statements in the script and all variable assignments are polluting the console.

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue, that I thought I might share.
If your statement is not within a function, it will print to the console.
As soon as the assignment is within a function it does not, hope this helps someone out there.